# Is there an alternative to MQTT shared subscription?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, mqtt

I am using the RabbitMQ MQTT plugin as my broker and node.js MQTT.js library as my MQTT client.

Unfortunately, RabbitMQ's MQTT plugin has not yet provide support for MQTT v5 which added shared subscription support. My end goal is to make sure that with multiple subscribers, subscribing to the same topics, when a message come only one subscriber will receive the message instead of all of them.

So if there a way to implement this type of round-robin queue with MQTT 3.1.1.?

Thanks